# How to disable native select dialog with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the standard select UI dialog with a custom popup selector in order to organize the availabel options better.

How can I prevent the standard dialog from opening, while opening my own pupup for selecting options?

I tried this in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#filter_brand").on("click", function() {
    // $('#filter_brand').prop("disabled", true);
    $("#popup_brand").popup("open");
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="popup" id="popup_brand" class="ui-content" data-theme="e">

  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">

    <li data-role="list-divider">Populäre Marken</li>

    <li>Brand 1</li>
    <li>Brand 2</li>

    <li data-role="list-divider">Alle Marken</li>

    <li>Brand 3</li>
    <li>Brand 4</li>

  </ul>

</div>

<select name="brand" id="filter_brand" data-mini="true" class="filter_brand">
  <option>Marke auswählen</option>
</select>
```

Now, that will open the dialog popup, but in the same time the native dialog.

How can I prevent the native dialog from opening?

My framework is jQuery 2.1.4 and jQuery mobile 1.4.5.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong event - the one you are looking for is `mousedown`

```js
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();  
  
  console.log('Clicked!')
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```